# WebClient and caching in Silverlight + WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, caching, webclient

I am using WebClient to download a JSON file everytime my WP7 application loads. I am loading all the details in one shot and that too from a server endpoint serving this JSON. The obvious problem I faced was the caching. It was always loading the stale copy. But I tackled this issue by adding a dummy URL paramater at the end.

However, the JSON changes very rarely. So I still need to utilize the caching technique that the WebClient automatically uses. To do this I initially request a call to the server's JSON version something like, `http://myserver/JSONVersion`. This JSONVersion gets updated any time JSON is updated.

Once I get it, i append it to my url `http://myserver/myjson.json?v=(JSONVERSION)`. This has solved my entire problem. However, I feel this is very ugly and has unnecessary excess code+logic floating around. I am hoping the HTTP Cache headers have a work around similar to the one that I am having. If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I found no better solution than the one I currently have.